# im not getting output for triangle program using multiple classes

Tags: java, methods, printing, geometry, output

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Triangle {
// inputing the intgers of the triangle
public void inputTriangleSides()
{
    System.out.println("Enter your triangle side lengths");
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int side1; 
    int side2; 
    int side3;
    System.out.println("Enter three integers to form a triangle:");
    side1 = keyboard.nextInt();
    side2 = keyboard.nextInt();
    side3 = keyboard.nextInt();
}
// determines if the three number make a triangle
public void ifTriangle (int side1, int side2, int side3)
{

    if (side1+side2> side3 && side1+side3>side2 && side2+side3>side1)
    {
        System.out.println("it a triangle");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println ("Not a Triangle");
    }
}
// sorts the numbers from lowest to highest
public static void displaySortedNumbers(int side1, int side2,  int side3 ){

    if ((side1 < side2) && (side2 < side3) &&(side1 <side3)){
        System.out.println("The sorted numbers are " + side1 + " " + side2 + " " + side3);
    }
    if ((side1 < side2) && (side2 > side3)){
        System.out.println("The sorted numbers are " + side1 + " " + side3 + " " + side2);
    }
    if ((side1 > side2) && (side2 > side3)){
        System.out.println("The sorted numbers are " + side3 + " " + side2 + " " + side1);
    }
    if ((side1 < side2) && (side2 > side3)){
        System.out.println("The sorted numbers are " + side3 + " " + side1 + " " + side2);
    }
    if ((side1 > side2) && (side2 > side3) && (side1>side3)){
        System.out.println("The sorted numbers are " + side2 + " " + side3 + " " + side1);
    }
    if ((side1 > side2) && (side2 < side3)){
        System.out.println("The sorted numbers are " + side2 + " " + side1 + " " + side3);
    }
}

//determines the type of triangle the three intgers form
public void displayType(int side1, int side2,int side3)
{
    if(( side1+side2 > side3))

        if(( side1==side2) && (side2==side3))//tell if equalateral
        {
            System.out.println("Equalateral Triangle.");
        }
        else if (( side1==side2) & (side2 != side3) || (side1 == side3) & (side3 != side1))//tells if isosceles
        {
            System.out.println ("Isosceles Triangle.");
        }
        else if ((side1 != side2) & (side2 != side3))//tells if scalene
        {
            System.out.println("Scalene Triangle.");        
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Not a triangle");
    }

}//missing return statement
// determines the perimeter
public int perimeter (int side1,int side2, int side3)
{
    if (side1+side2> side3 && side1+side3>side2 && side2+side3>side1)
    {
        int perimeter= side1+side2+side3;
        return perimeter;
    }
    else
        return 0;
}

public void output(int side1 , int side2,  int side3, int perimeter)
{System.out.println(perimeter);
}
}
```

this is placed into this class.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TriangleDriver {
public static void main(String args[]){
Triangle yourTriangle= new Triangle();
yourTriangle.inputTriangleSides();
}

public void inputTriangleSides()
{
    Triangle yourTriangle= new Triangle();
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int side1; 
    int side2; 
    int side3;
    System.out.println("Enter three integers to form a triangle:");
    side1 = keyboard.nextInt();
    side2 = keyboard.nextInt();
    side3 = keyboard.nextInt();
    yourTriangle.ifTriangle(side1,side2,side3); // is it a triangle?
    yourTriangle.displaySortedNumbers(side1,side2,side3); // sorts the number
    yourTriangle.displayType(side1,side2,side3); // type of triangle
    yourTriangle.perimeter(side1,side2,side3); // type of perimeter

}
}
```

When I input the numbers, I'm not getting the output which are supposed to be print statements that I need from the method, What I'm I missing exactly? Also is there a way to loop it mean when it done with the output it will ask do you want to make more triangles? Yes or no. Yes it will do the program again. No it will end it. Do you use an if else statement?

Comment: I would sort it this way: 
`int[] sides = {side1, side2, side3};
Arrays.sort(sides);`

Comment: not allowed to use arrays right now.

Answer (score 0):

You have a method called inputTriangleSides() in both class Triangle and class TriangleDriver.

In your main program, you call the method in the Triangle class, which doesn't print out anything as you can see.

Try

```
TriangleDriver yourTriangle= new TriangleDriver();
yourTriangle.inputTriangleSides();
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

Since this looks like "homework" or a test problem, I am going to make some suggestions about structure, rather than provide exact code.

First, split your program into a Controller class and a Triangle class.  Have the Controller class, read input sides and make a new Triangle object from those sides `trialTriangle = new Triangle(side1, side2, side3)`.  In the Triangle class, create the following methods: `boolean isTriangle()`; `String getType()`, and `int getPerimeter()`; Some logic hints: inside Triangle after sorting the sides (say in an array `sides[] = new int[3]` determine if you have a triangle before seeing what type of triangle (to make sure 0, 0, 0 is not shown as an equilateral triangle); equilateral is same as side[0] == side[2] because sides are in order; then determine isocolese (you only need to see if the first two or last two sorted sides are equal).

In the "controller" class, get a line and see if user asked to "end"; if not create triangle and print results and loop.